# Spring integration ftp adapter and batch processing

Tags: java, spring-integration

I need to poll FTP server and process new or changed files. I use Spring Integration 5.3.2 with inbound FTP adapter and poller with fixed rate of 5 seconds. All files downloaded immediately in local directory, but integration flow underlying handlers invokes after every 5 seconds for each file. I want to process downloaded list of files immediately in concurent threads, but poll ftp each 5 seconds after flow ends. How can i do it?

```
@Bean
fun ftpInboundFlow(): IntegrationFlow {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            .maxFetchSize(ftpProperties.maxFetchSize)
            .remoteDirectory(ftpProperties.remoteDirectory)
            .localDirectory(File(ftpProperties.downloadDirectory))
            .filter(FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(SimpleMetadataStore(), "ftp-"))
            .regexFilter(".*\\.zip$")
    ) { e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(Duration.ofSeconds(5))) }
            .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newWorkStealingPool()))
            .transform(unZipTransformer())
            .handle { m -> LOGGER.info("Unzipped {}", m.headers[FileHeaders.FILENAME]) }
            .get()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `maxMessagesPerPoll` - it defaults to 1; -1 means infinity.

```
Pollers.fixedRate(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).maxMessagesPerPoll(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like you want to use an `MGET` command from the `FtpOutboundGateway`. So, you still can have a plain poller with empty string payload to send, something like  `IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "")` with a desired poller options.

The calling an `Ftp.outboundGateway()` with an `MGET` command against a remote dir will give you a `List<File>` as a reply message. So, you are free to do anything with your files as a batch.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway